# how to store data into dynamic array

Tags: c++

I have this program that asks user to enter a number and ask the user if they want to view input history. So i was wondering if my code is correct. I want to know if doing `cin>>num[count-1]` is correct or is there a correct way to get the data the user inputs. Here it is:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    const int size = 20;
    int *num = new int[size];
    char answer;
    int count = 1;
    while(true){
    cout<<"ENTER NUMBER: \n";
    cin>>num[count-1];
    cout<<"TRY AGAIN? ";
    cin>>answer;
        switch(answer){
            case 'y':
                count++;
                system("cls");
                break;
            default:

                cout<<"INPUT HISTORY: \n";
                for(int i=0;i<=count-1;i++){
                    cout<<num[i]<<endl;
                }
                count++;
        }
    }
    delete [] num;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to know is doing cin>>num[count-1]` is correct or is there a correct way to get the data the user inputs.

Comment: you should use `vector<int>` and `push_back`, not int[] and count

Comment: Isn't it a question more for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a c-style code. You have the **std::array** and **std::vector** to help you to write a more secure and clean code. Because your tag in your question is dynamic-arrays I suggest to use the **std::vector**.
Bellow you can check out your code could be with the replacement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    //int *num = new int[size]; //normally you don't need to use new. Let the c++ manage it for you
    vector<int> num;
    char answer;

    while (true) {
          cout << "ENTER NUMBER: \n";
          num.emplace_back();         //Create a new element to vector num
          cin >> num.back();          //set this new element

          cout << "TRY AGAIN? ";
          cin >> answer;

          if (answer == 'y')
             system("cls");
          else {
            cout<<"INPUT HISTORY: \n";
            for (auto& numEle : num)    //It will interate over all elements of num
                cout<< numEle <<endl;
            //break; //Maybe you want to break the loop here
          }
    }
//    delete [] num;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It will work, but you could declare 'count' equal to 0. Then change the cin line to 'cin >> num[count];'. Also, you could move the 'count++' to be out of switch declaration because in any case you need to increase its value.

Answer (score 0):

I will first show you the problems in your code. I put in comments.

Then I will explain you, why your input is wrong. Also the answer from user TheArquitect is wrong and will finally lead to a memory overflow.

Your program will also have a desastrous result.

First see the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; // In C++ we never use this statement. Why? See:
                     // You will find at least 1000 comments in Stackoverflow

int main() {

    const int size = 20; // In C++ we use constexpr for compile time constants
    int* num = new int[size];   // In C++ we  
                                // Do not use raw pointers for owned memory
                                // Do not use new
                                // Do Not use C-Style arrays
                                // Generally: std::vector should be used
                                // Or at least std::unique_ptr and std::make_unique
                                // Also, this 2 lines are nonesense. It is the same as int num[20];
    char answer;                // All variables should always be initialized
                                // Variables should be in the scope, where they are necessary
    int count = 1;              // YOu could use uniform initialization
                                // Arrays start with index 0 in C++ (also in C )
    while (true) {              // You are creating an endless loop with desastrous effect
        cout << "ENTER NUMBER: \n";
        cin >> num[count - 1];  // No, this will not work. Explanation in text
        cout << "TRY AGAIN? ";  
        cin >> answer;          // No, this will not work. Explanation in text
        switch (answer) {       // Switch with only one case can always be expressed with if elese
        case 'y':
            count++;
            system("cls");      // This is a non portable solution 
            break;
        default:

            cout << "INPUT HISTORY: \n";
            for (int i = 0; i <= count - 1; i++) {  // Nearly Never use <= in for loops
                                                    // Use for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
                                                    // Do use ++i insted of i++
                cout << num[i] << endl;
            }
            count++;
        }   // This is an endless loop. count will always be increased. If greater than 20
            // then the memory will be corrupted. This will happen always
    }
    delete[] num; // Dead code. Will never be invoked
    return 0;
}
```

OK. Now, besides the major bugs and the killing out of bounds problem, here the explanation for the problem with inputting data.

Rule: You must always check, if the input operation worked. For that you can check the state of the stream. Additionally, if you do not consume the input data (because of an erronous input by the user), this data is still in the input buffer. And in the next loop it will be read again (without waiting for new user input). The status of the input stream may still be wrong and it will also not read because of this.

Then the endless loop starts to run without user input and corrupts your memory.

You may check, by simply inputting a letter instead of a number.

How to fix?

Again, you must check the state of the stream after reading. This is usually done in the form:

```
if (std::cin >> number)
```

Why does this work? Because: The inserter operator returns a reference to the stream (so std::cin) and the boolean '!' not-operator for the `std::istream` is overwritten. It will show, if the state of the stream is still ok or not.

OK, understood. Now. What to do in case of error? 2 operations:

- Clear all failure bits in the state of the stream --> `std::cin.clear()`
- Eat up everything that is still in the input buffer --> `std::cin.ignore()`

You could write:

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

I assume that you are learing C++ in a class and learn about `new` and `delete`. As said, you should not use it. But because teacher request this often in the classes, I will show you now a better solution than yours, still using new, but without (most of) the problems.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {

    // We want to create a dynamic array with 20 elements
    constexpr size_t MaxArraySize{ 20U };

    // Allocate a dynamic arry on the heap
    int* numberArray = new int[MaxArraySize];

    // Read maximum 20 numbers into our dynamic array
    for (size_t currentArrayIndex{}; currentArrayIndex < MaxArraySize; ) {

        // Inform the user that he should ent now a number
        std::cout << "Enter number: \n";

        // Read the number and check, if this worked
        if (std::cin >> numberArray[currentArrayIndex]) {

            // Now ask, if the user wants to continue or stop
            std::cout << "Doy you want to enter more numbers? ('y' or 'n'): ";

            // Define variable answer and get user input and check, if ok
            if (char answer{}; std::cin >> answer) {

                // Does the user want to continue?
                if ('y' == answer) {

                    // Yes, continue. Increment array index
                    ++currentArrayIndex;
                }
                else {

                    // No, the user does not want to continue. Show the values entered so far
                    std::cout << "Input History:\n";
                    for (size_t i{}; i <= currentArrayIndex; ++i) { // NOTE: <= becuase index has not yet been incrementet
                        std::cout << numberArray[i] << "\n";
                    }

                    break; // Stop the for loop and end the program
                }
            }
            else {
                // Strange, input of a character did not work. Should not happen. Terminate program
                std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Problem with input!\n\n";

                break; // Stop the for loop and end the program
            }
        }
        else {
            // The user entered someting wrong, or the input did not work for any other reason
            // Inform user about problem
            std::cerr << "\n*** Error: No number could be read!\n\n";

            // Clear error flag and comsume whatever is in the input buffer
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }
    // Release dynamic allocated memory
    delete[] numberArray;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this, I have learned a lot. And yes you are right are prof wants us to use the new and delete.